# Print Connected Components Scala

Tags: graph, scala

Given a file containing adjacent IDs:

```
i1, i2, i5
i3, i4
i2, i6, i7
i4, i8
i9, i3
```

I would like to print each of the connected components:

```
i1, i2, i5, i6, i7
i3, i4, i8, i9
```

I decided to accomplish this using a BFS on a `Map` datastructure:

```
/* Input, can be read from file easily by splitting on ", " */
val lines = List(List("i1", "i2", "i5"),
    List("i3", "i4"),
    List("i2", "i6", "i7"),
    List("i4", "i8"),
    List("i9", "i3"))
/* finds all sequential pairs */
val pairs =  lines.flatMap(x => x.dropRight(1).zip(x.drop(1)))

/* each pair should be symmetric (we are in an undirected graph) */
val pSym = pairs.flatMap(x => List(x, x.swap))

/* create an empty adjacency map: id -> (List of adjacent edges) */
val vertices = lines.flatten.distinct
val defMap = vertices.map(_ -> List[String]()).toMap

/* populate the default map with the actual adjacencies */
val adjMap = pSym.foldLeft{defMap}(
    (acc, x) => acc + (x._1 -> (acc(x._1) :+ x._2))
)

/* BFS algo on map representation of graph */
def mapBFS(adjMap: Map[String, List[String]]): List[List[String]] =
{
    val v = adjMap.keys
    var globalVisits = List[String]()
    def BFS_r(elems: List[String], visited: List[List[String]]): Option[List[List[String]]] =
    {
        val newNeighbors = elems.flatMap(adjMap(_)).filterNot(visited.flatten.contains).distinct
        if (newNeighbors.isEmpty)
            Some(visited)
        else
            BFS_r(newNeighbors, newNeighbors :: visited)
    }
    v.flatMap(x =>{
        if (globalVisits.contains(x))
            None
        else
        {
            val vi: List[String] = BFS_r(List(x), List(List(x))).get.flatten
            globalVisits = globalVisits ++ vi
            Some(vi)
        }
    }).toList
}

mapBFS(adjMap).foreach{println}
```

This gives me the desired result:

```
List(i7, i1, i6, i2, i5)
List(i8, i4, i3, i9)
```

However I feel that this code is not very functional (esp. with the side-effects of updating `globalVisits` in `mapBFS`) and I feel like some the data manipulation at the beginning is pretty inefficient. Any thoughts on improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always translate loops into a tail-recursive function.  Then all you need to do is pass state around as function parameters instead of mutating it in place.  IIRC, Scala supports tail-call optimization of direct recursion with the appropriate annotation.  That should be good enough in this case.

You actually have done this for `BFS_r`.  You basically just need to do the same thing with the rest of the code.

But first, you're using a lot of `List`s that would probably be better off as `Set`s or `Map`s.  Also, you're keeping track of the nodes that have been visited (`globalVisits`).  I would keep track of the portion of the graph that has not been visited instead -- at least with a tail-recursive solution, since we'll have to get rid of the `flatMap`.

The first thing is to replace the `flatMap` with a tail-recursive function:

```
@tailrec
def loop(unvisited: Map[String, List[String]], accumulator: List[List[String]]): List[List[String]] = {
  if unvisited.empty {
    // We're done => return the accumulator
    return acc
  }
  else{
    // Get the next seed node
    // (Since maps are typically unordered, head is an arbitrary node
    //  that hasn't been visited yet.)
    val seed = unvisited.head

    // Find the component connected to seed
    component = BFS_r(List(seed), List(List(seed)).get.flatten)

    // Iterate, with new unvisited map and component list
    // The new unvisited will have all the nodes in component removed
    // The new accumulator has component added
    return loop(unvisited -- component, component :: accumulator)
}
```

Then kick it off with:

```
return loop(adjMap, List())
```

I haven't done a lot of work with Scala yet, so I can't say this is 100% valid Scala or will work at all.  But hopefully the intention is clear.  One important to note is that `Map` and `List` here are the immutable variants (i.e., from `scala.collections.immutable` rather than `scala.collections.mutable`).